# using jquery.i18n.properties.js with Grails

Tags: jquery, grails, internationalization, properties-file

I'm using `jquery.i18n.properties.js` with `Grails 2.5.6` application, but I think it's not working well due to the error mentioned a bit later. Below is my code in grails view.

the GSP:

```
<head>
 <asset:javascript src="jquery.i18n.properties-min-1.0.9.js"/>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.i18n.properties({
        name: 'messages',
        path: 'i18n/', //E:/IntelljWS/MyProject/grails-app/
        mode: 'both',
        language: 'en', 
        callback: function () {

            $("#error").text($.i18n.prop('msg.test'));
        }
    });
});
```

Below is one of the messages defined in `messages.properties` file and used in the sample code:

```
 msg.test=Test message
```

What shown in the `#error` is `[msg.test]`

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Have you found your solution finally?

Comment: @Tung trying any workaround may reach me to my goal

Comment: I have worked with `i18n-asset-pipeline:1.0.6` recently. It fits into either retrieving local messages or customising internationalisation. Do you want to need that help?

Comment: @Tung if you got any documentation for it I'll be grateful

Answer (score 0):

What I will present below about `i18n-asset-pipeline` grails plugin which is doing the same job as `jquery.i18n.properties.js` as such. You probably find a few implementations of `jquery.i18n.properties.js` on [grails plugin portal](https://grails.org/plugins). I'm not entirely sure you will be happy with my suggestion. However, I would say that using this plugin will help us minimise the effort to maintain and call tag lib `g:message` in **both grails views and external javascript files**.

If you feel confident to play with `i18n-asset-pipeline`, please take a closer look at [its documentation](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/amc-world/i18n-asset-pipeline). Below are the summarised baby steps I have been doing with `grails 2.5.6`.

**Step 1: Declare the plugin in** `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
plugins {
   ...
   runtime 'org.grails.plugins:i18n-asset-pipeline:1.0.6'
   ...
}
```

**Step 2: Define your messages properties in the appropriate files**

In Resource Bundle messages under `grails-app/i18n` directory, you add your languages of interest files, such as `messages_fr.properties`, `messages_vi.properties`, etc. To demonstrate how this works, I have `welcome.message` just display a welcome message on the index page in these files `messages_{fr,es,vi}.properties`.

**Step 3: Define** `i18n` files in `assets/javascripts/i18n` **directory**

After starting the application first, you will see this directory. Creating the same set of files, i.e. `messages.i18n`, `messages_{es,fr,vi}.i18n`. Inside these files, we just put the properties that were added in `messages_{es,fr,vi}.properties` files or the properties you want to display in only specific languages.

**Step 4: Set the default language (optional)**

Leaving the following snippet in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` file

```
beans = {
   localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver) {
      defaultLocale = new Locale("fr", "FR")
      java.util.Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale)
   }
}
```

**Step 5: How to use i18n plugin**

In views, we can load i18n language default setting and display message properties something along those lines.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo | BioModels</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <script>

    </script>
    <g:set var="locale" value="${session.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'}"/>
    <asset:i18n locale="${locale}"/>
</head>

<body>
<h2><g:message code="welcome.message"/> </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**Step 6: Testing**

Open a tab in your web browser, retrieving your page, `http://localhost:8900/i18ndemo/demo/`, for instance, it will render the content of `welcome.message` property in the default language which was set up in `resources.groovy`. If you want to switch to other languages straightaway, type `?lang=es` after the previous URL. That looks like `http://localhost:8900/i18ndemo/demo/?lang=es`

After getting through those steps, I believe you will obtain your need.

The sample project has been also pushed to bitbucket found [here](https://bitbucket.org/itersdesktop/i18ndemo/src).

I hope this answer would help you solve your problem.